# @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY) not working when i use a wrapper class and return the result

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

My Controller Code is

```
public TestClass<DtoV1> getAllAlliance(@RequestHeader(ID_HEADER) String id,Pageable pageable,                               PagedResourcesAssembler pagedResourcesAssembler)
    {

        Page<DtoV1> pageResource  = serviceV1.findPagedPrefixesById(pageable, id);
        PagedResources<DtoV1> pagedResources = pagedResourcesAssembler.toResource(pageResource);
        TestClass<DtoV1> testClass = new TestClass<>(pageResource.getContent(),pagedResources.getLinks());
        return testClass;
    }
```

My TestClass Wrapper is

```
enter code herepublic class TestClass<T> {


public String name;
public Collection<T> content;
public List<Link> links;
public String[] st= new String[0];
public TestClass(Collection<T> content,List<Link> links)
{
    this.content = content;
    this.name="sunil";
    this.links = links;
}
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
@JsonProperty("_name")
public String getName()
{
    return this.name;
}
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
@JsonProperty("_st")
public String[] getSt() {
    return st;
}

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
@JsonProperty("_embedded")
public Collection<T> getContent()
{
    return this.content;
}

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
@JsonProperty("_links")
public List<Link> getLinks() {
    return this.links;
}}
```

My Result is

```
{
    "_name": "sunil",
    "_embedded": [
        {
            "key": "0000435",
            "type": "Test",
            "issuing": "temp",
            "issued": "temp",
            "dateIssued": "1989-10-22",
            "links": []
        }],
    "_links": [
        {
            "rel": "first",
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/v1?page=0&size=20",
            "hreflang": null,
            "media": null,
            "title": null,
            "type": null,
            "deprecation": null
        }]
}
```

If you see i have created an **string empty array st** in test class it is not coming but why rest are coming

Expected null and empty values will not  come as using **@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)**

Comment: It is working as expected . Since you have included `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)` on `_st`. it is empty string array . it will not come in result

Comment: Remove  @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)  from  getSt()

Comment: @Ajeet47 you didnt see it what i want  i want the null values should not come but they are coming

Comment: @SunilKumar did you mean _links? if that is the case then you should add annotation on Link class too.

Comment: its a java class libaray

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The  Problem is Thridparty object . So if go with the concept i believe that we can not ignore null or empty of  other class objects if they do not contain ignore null annotation

To do this what we can do we can use mixin with objectmapper.